# Firestore limit on updating data about once per second; why do I seem to be able to go past it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) and the [quotas chart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) show that a document can only be updated about once per second. Why do I seem to be able to update a document more than once per second with no problem?

I tried a simple "for loop" and all writes seem to go through:

```
 const db = firebase.firestore(firebase.app("prjID"));
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     console.log(`updating /test/test with test:${i} ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
     db.doc(`/test/test`).update({ test: i });
 }
```

log shows : 
[image]

I am wondering if someone knows the supposed server response when multiple write operations are attempted in less than a second i.e, beyond the limit that I seemingly can ignore?

If I am missing something and the limit means something different any explanation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI for whoever might wonder about this. This is not a hard limit enforced by Firebase but rather an indication of the system's capabilities. Read more into the answer I got from Firebase [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/495#event-1463399312). So if you think you are going to perform thousands of writes to a document in short amount of time then you should think about it. But for a few writes here and there, systems seems to be capable of handling it in timely manner.

Comment: If the limit is reached, will the operation fail or wait?

Comment: As I explained, there is no hard limit so it's just a matter so as I understand, it becomes a chance of weather the system handles your job or not. For my case I don't go above 10 or 15 updates per second max and it seems to be fine with that.

Comment: @TheeBen so what happens when it fails? Data loss?

Comment: I can't really provide a definite answer and you may be better off asking Firebase folks but based on my experience you won't ever get there to have to deal with this limit in a real application unless your app is too big which in that case I doubt you'd still be using firebase or by then they've surpassed expectations or... you get the idea...

Comment: @OliverDixon Silent failure.  It doesn't write, but it doesn't throw an error either. Not optimal. You get here pretty quick if you're trying to do aggregation.  For example, if you're using cloud functions to process a running count.

Comment: When you write to a document too quickly, you begin to receive  `ABORTED` errors as described in this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/troubleshooting#aborted). The point at which you begin to see these errors [depends on your workload](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document).

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have a hard limit on document updates per second: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document

When writing at sufficiently high rates to documents using transactions they will eventually conflict and one will abort. Abort errors are reported to the client.

The above example demonstrates rough performance of a particular workload.

Answer (score -5):

The limit for writes per second is 2,500. These writes have a total limit of 2.5MB.

> Maximum writes per second per database (at beta)  2,500 (up to 2.5 MiB per second)

If your internet connection is fast enough, you could try running that loop over 2500 times to see if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is max wrties to db per second, I am asking for write to one document which is also addressed in the same chart. Cheers

Comment: @TheeBen Got it. Sorry for misunderstanding. I tried a write loop 250 times and noticed it pausing about every 10 seconds. Not sure if that's just me. My best guess is that since the product is still in beta, somebody at Firebase was making some changes and messed up the quota. You could message Firebase Support and get them to take a look at it. (Not sure why you'd want to except to find out what's wrong). I did check the status page and nothing's wrong with Firestore.

Comment: np, I doubt something from firebase is wrong but it doesn't hurt, I will try.

Comment: So I asked and here's the response. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/495#event-1463399312